# Django cache NotImplementedError

Tags: python, django, caching, django-debug-toolbar

I can do this from the Python shell:

```
from django.core.cache import *
cache.clear()
```

But when I try this from `signals.py`

```
from django.core.cache import *
....
....
def clear_cache(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if sender.__name__ in ['Foo', 'Bar']:
        cache.clear()
```

I get:

```
NotImplementedError at /edit/bar/
subclasses of BaseCache must provide a clear() method
```

I'm using redis, but I'm having the same problem with memcached.
Just at the error, I can see that `cache = <django.core.cache.DefaultCacheProxy object at 0x10e566e90>`

I must be doing something horribly wrong?

EDIT:
Here's a clue.
From inside `signals.py`, `cache.clear` is:

```
<bound method CacheStatTracker.clear of <CacheStatTracker for <redis_cache.cache.RedisCache object at 0x10a39dbd0>>>
```

While from the console:

```
<bound method RedisCache.clear of <redis_cache.cache.RedisCache object at 0x10bf1e0d0>>
```

What the heck?

Comment: There, it appears as though debug-toolbar is interfering somehow. I disabled `debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel` and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing everything with `*`, have you tried:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
```

Docs on Caching: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#accessing-the-cache

Comment: Yes, I've tried `from django.core.cache import cache`

Comment: Here's a clue, inside the app, `cache.clear` is `<bound method CacheStatTracker.clear of <CacheStatTracker for <redis_cache.cache.RedisCache object at 0x10a39dbd0>>>`. While from the console, it's `<bound method RedisCache.clear of <redis_cache.cache.RedisCache object at 0x10bf1e0d0>>`.